# Return Observable from inside nested callbacks functions

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

Good afternoon!

I'm currently developing a web app in Angular2/4 and I have a problem with Observables. The goal is, inside a component, to call a function and when that function finishes, I want some code to be executed. So, the code in the **"myComp.component.ts"** file is:

```
this.myService.myFunc1().subscribe(() => {
    // this code has to be executed after myFunc1() finishes.
});
```

The problem is inside the *"myFunc1()"* function of the **"myService.service.ts"** file. The structure of this function is the following:

1. Define the function, which returns an `Observable<Status>`, where Status object is just `{ status: 'ok' }`.
2. Call the function *"myFunc2()"* from another service, which returns an Observable, and do some staff.
3. Call the function *"myFunc3()"* from another service, which returns an Observable and has to be executed after *"myFunc2()"* finishes.
4. Call the function *"myFunc4()"* from another service, which returns an Observable and has to be executed after *"myFunc3()"* finishes.
5. Return the `{ status: 'ok' }` into the *"myComp.component.ts"* in order the other code inside the subscribe() to be executed.

So what I need is (3) nested calls of some functions, each and every one of them to be executed after the previous one. The most simple method is given below:

```
myFunc1(): Observable<Status> {
    // some code and then call of myFunc2()
    this.myService2.myFunc2().subscribe(data => {
       // do some staff here and then call of myFunc3()
       this.myService3.myFunc3().subscribe(data2 => {
          // do some other staff and then call of myFunc4()
          this.myService4.myFunc4().subscribe(data3 => {
             // do staff and then return program flow into the Component
             return Observable.of<Status>({status: 'ok'});
          });
       });
    });
}
```

But of course the `return Observable.of<Status>({status: 'ok'});` doesn't work. I have been searching for a solution on the Internet and other Stackoverflow questions and I found suggestions like use of *flatMap()*, *mergeMap()*, *switchMap()* etc. I think that these solutions cannot be used in my case, because each function has to be executed after the other.

What can I do? What I miss here? Thank you in advance for your help and your time!

Comment: you can try to combine your multiple observers using [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) or [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) depending on your requirement!

Comment: First off you're not returning anything in your function, so it will not compile. Secondly even if you did return in this case "subscribe" would return a Subscription and not an Observable<Status>. Using switchMap is is the correct way to chain. Make sure you return and then subscribe to the method when you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What You are looking for is switchMap or mergeMap. switch map is better it will cancel previous request if new comes out.

```
myFunc1(): Observable<Status> {
    // some code and then call of myFunc2()
    return this.myService2.myFunc2()
      .switchMap(data => {
       // do some staff here and then call of myFunc3()
       return this.myService3.myFunc3()
      }).switchMap(data2 => {
          // do some other staff and then call of myFunc4()
          return this.myService4.myFunc4()
      }).switchMap(data3 => {
             // do staff and then return program flow into the Component
             return Observable.of<Status>({status: 'ok'});
          });
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: It works. It also needs `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`. Thank you very much!