# Angular 5 - Subscribing an Observable after a callback function(subscribe cannot read property subscribe of undefined)

Tags: observable, angular5, subscribe

I have to return observable response to my parent component after callback function executed.

if i put **return this._httpService.insertRMS(url, body);** without callback, i able to get the response whatever success or error.

As i understood able to consume subscribe, only in observable type of response. is any other is available to consume observable response after callback function executed.

I have written **getParcelInfo** function inside callback function, due to duplicate avoid, since it needs so many times for other functionality[image]

comp1.ts

```
parcelinfo(){
this._pmsToRMSService.createOrderDelivery(351).subscribe(//Error
  response => {
    alert("success");
  },
  error => {
    alert("error");
  });
}
```

comp2.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class PMSToRMSService {

private getParcelInfo(parcelid, callback): any {

    let url = serviceAPI.urlParcel + parcelid;
    this._httpService.getData(url).subscribe(
        response => {
            callback(response);
        },
        error => {
            callback(error);
        });
}

public createOrderDelivery(parcelid: number): Observable<any> {

   return this.getParcelInfo(parcelid, pmsResponse => {          

                let body = pmsResponse;

                let url = serviceAPI.urlRMSCreateOrder;

                return this._httpService.insertRMS(url, body);//Output Need
});
}
```

}

Comment: I followed this article and resolved the issue...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326446/return-observable-from-inside-nested-callbacks-functions

Answer (score 0):

```
private getParcelInfo(parcelid, callback): any {

    let url = serviceAPI.urlParcel + parcelid;
    this._httpService.getData(url).subscribe(
        response => {
            callback(response);
        },
        error => {
            callback(error);
        });
}
```

**getParcelInfo** function is not returning anything as the error message suggested.
Also **you are making a subscription here** (you are calling the subscribe method) with that in mind your could return (if you add return keyword) a subscription Object instead of a Observable (take care of it).

This is how should look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class PMSToRMSService {

private getParcelInfo(parcelid, callback): any {
    let url = serviceAPI.urlParcel + parcelid;
    return this._httpService.getData(url)
        .do(response => callback(response),
            error => callback(error));
}

public createOrderDelivery(parcelid: number): Observable<any> {
   return this.getParcelInfo(parcelid, pmsResponse => {
                let body = pmsResponse;
                let url = serviceAPI.urlRMSCreateOrder;
                return this._httpService.insertRMS(url, body);
          });
   }
}
```

Comment: This one return getParcelInfo response instead of insertRMS. I have googled and implemented switchMap seems fine now.